# Issues with Unity after installing and uninstalling FGLRX again

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I tried to install FGLRX drivers on Ubuntu 13.04, but that didn't work out.

I then went back to the open source drivers (via `update-manager`) but I couldn't boot into a graphical OS.

I got a black screen with a prompt to log in.

I got in, launched `lightdm` manually, and reinstalled the OSS drivers... and now I have them installed, and I even seem to be using them (`chrome://gpu` reports that I am, and I can move things around the screen).

But everything is screwed up - I can't get Unity to launch, I'm still booting into the black screen, and I can't seem to fix this.

Help?

**edit**: I removed `fglrx` completely, and I now boot into a UI, but it's just a desktop background. No Unity.

**edit2**: I can now launch Unity manually... but it doesn't have any of my old settings, and doesn't have any plugins etc. So that's still not working great.

**edit3**: I went into CCSM and reenabled all of the plugins like Unity and gave default settings. IDK what else but something broke Unity, I can no longer launch it.

Comment: try making a new user profile and, check Unity works in it

Comment: @Naveen: I tried to reproduce the problem that the OP was asking about. Everything that the OP described happened in my case. Making new user gives unity back, but it is unbelievably slow. I suppose somewhere in the XOrg system, drivers/settings got messed up. Generating a new xorg.conf didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried this with KDE? I wonder if this is a Unity thing only.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix my Unity by switching back to the Xorg driver and renaming the `~/.config` folder. I'm not sure exactly which configs got messed up, but starting fresh without config files worked for me.