# xorg-edgers PPA doesn't seem to include fglrx-installer package

Tags: ati, xorg, ppa, fglrx

I'm trying to use the xorg-edgers PPA to install the latest ATI drivers on my laptop:

https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

According to that link there is a package named fglrx-installer for 12.10 (Quantal):

> ```
>  fglrx-installer  2:12.100~beta7-0ubuntu1~xedgers~quantal1
> ```

So I tried to add the PPA and install the package like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx-installer
```

It simply fails and reports that no such package exists.  So how do I get this thing installed?

```
$ sudo apt-get install fglrx-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fglrx-installer
$ apt-cache search fglrx-installer
$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages you might be looking for in this PPA are **fglrx** and **fglrx-amdcccle**.

But I recommend making a backup of your Ubuntu parititon, for example using **Clonezilla**, before trying this PPA.

Comment: That's confusing because those are the names of the packages that get installed in the "other" tab of software sources.  :/

+1 on making a backup though.  I tried installing these 2 packages and it not only didn't properly run, it also had the AMD watermark on it (yes, you can remove that).  I would up completely uninstalling and then manually installing the driver from AMD's site.  Of course, you have to **apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)** otherwise you cannot build DKMS.

Oh well I wanted to use the package management system but guess I can't.

Comment: These are different ways of installing the AMD proprietary display driver: 1) Directly from AMD website, 2) From the "Additional Drivers" tab of "Software Sources", 3) From xorg-edgers PPA. I think it depends on a number of factors which provides the best solution, and one may try each by making a proper backup.

Comment: @Sadi: I think the OP knows about all of that. Also, when you say "a number of factors," it would be helpful if you could specify. As for your answer above: that doesn't work, because it pulls in fglrx from the Ubuntu repos that is the same as the "additional hardware" tab. That is not what the OP wants, since the OP wants the latest driver (so do I, actually). Suffice it to say, xorg-edgers is broken.

Comment: I should also add that I've tried installing the ATI driver manually from the AMD website (yes, yes, I know about all the dependencies: been there, done that), but somehow the Unity is broken after install and even after I uninstalled the drivers, Unity was still broken. I couldn't find a way to recover (creating a new user gives Unity back, but it is unbelievably slow... somehow somewhere in the XOrg, the drivers/settings got messed up). Here is a related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280916.

Comment: @William: Thanks for the clarification/correction about **fglrx** and **xorg-edgers ppa**. It seems to me from experience and so much reading that it's a combination of hardware and software setup that might affect which driver will suit you best. I've tried all and the best I could achieve so far is using **the latest (13.3beta3) proprietary driver from AMD website which lets me switch between integrated Intel GPU and discrete AMD GPU using a small script as the AMD Control Center doesn't work unfortunately.**

Comment: @Sadi: Ah, thanks, this is useful! Could you confirm that 13.3betaX works on Ubuntu 13.04? Also, what is that script that you're referring to? I think that would be useful for many people, since most CPUs nowadays come with integrated GPUs.

Comment: @William: I've just tried several options under Ubuntu 13.04 but I couldn't get the AMD proprietary display driver work in any way. It's probably related with the new kernel: 3.8.x. So I'm back to using the Integrated (Intel) GPU only for now.

Comment: @William: I forgot, the script I used was merely for deleting and restoring (from a backup file) **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** and then re-login.